# Add SVG to folium map with Flask in Python

Tags: python, flask, svg, leaflet, folium

I have made a leaflet map in python with Folium. I have used markers and popup pictures, and saved the results with html. I then want to share this html with the rest of my team. I have found out that you can share the html file quit easly, but I dont like the file:///user/map.html format. So I want to share the map to the web with the help of Flask and Heroku.

The orignal map is created with folium, with the svg-files located at a folder called SVG:

```
html_svg='<img src="SVG//tot_prv_cpt.svg" alt="totalsondering" />'
```

This works fine. However, when i run the follwing code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def render_the_map():
    return render_template('map.html')

##    mimetypes.add_type('image/svg+xml', '.svg')
#def serve_content(svgFile):
#    return file('SVG/'+svgFile+'.svg').read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The SVG wont show up, and I get this error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2021 13:22:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2021 13:22:52] "GET /SVG//tot-grey.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2021 13:22:52] "GET /SVG//tot.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2021 13:22:52] "GET /SVG//tot_cpt.svg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I have tried to create a Static folder in the Flask app but give me the same result.

Anyone that got any tips on how to show SVG when uploading to the web with Flask ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking: I saved my Folium map as map.html and used Django and the following `jinja` in my `index.html`:

```
{% extends "venues/layout.html" %}
{% load static }
{% block body %}
        {% include 'venues/map.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The result is https://culturemapp.herokuapp.com/